# Is it possible to commit and push tree state to another branch during unfinished merge process?

Tags: git

I'm going thru a long, painful merge process. I'm not able to finish it at once, and I'd like to push current tree state to temporary, backup branch.
This shouldn't influence current merge process state. Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not without manually hacking the .git folder when restoring from your branch. Once you commit, the state of the files in the working folder is considered to be correct, even if they happen to include merge conflict markers.

Comment: Why do you have to commit at all? Can't you simply work through it in the time it takes to complete? If you need to work on other interim issues, perhaps you're looking for [worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) ?

Comment: ...because my work stored on server is safe